# Why does Urano Metria take double her magic the second time

Tags: fairy-tail

The first time Lucy casts Urano Metria she used her own power to defeat Angel with no problem. But the next time, when she uses it in The Grand Magic Games she has to combine her power with Gemini to cast it and says it was still weaker than the first time and since this was after her second origin was unlocked she would have at least 3 time as much magic energy (her origin would double it and gemini would double that) So what makes her first casting so strong.

Answer (score 1):

The first time she casted Urano Metria, she received the spell from Hibiki of Blue Pegasus. He gave her one chance to cast the spell which she successfully did but the spell wasn't her's. Hibiki's power is "Archive" : he is able to transform a lot of things in datas that he can transfers to people. Thanks to this power, **Hibiki has been able to give Lucy his knowledge about the spell and all his magic power** (he gave her so much of his power that he fainted instantly right after).

After casting it, she couldn't remember anything and she had to learn the spell all by herself. The trick she found to overcome the difficulty of the spell was to combine her magic power with Gemini's, like Naruto mastered Rasengan thank to his clones.

Hope that helps

> Sources :
>
> - Fairy Tail Manga: Chapter 144, Pages 14-20
> - Fairy Tail Manga: Chapter    385, Pages 14-17

Comment: I thought that Hibiki might have give her his magic power but that would mean that he had  3 times her power at least and frankly he doesn't seem that powerful. Also if he can transfer his magic power to someone else why doesn't he do that more after all that's a pretty helpful skill.

Comment: Even if he gave her his magic power that doesn't mean she didn't use her magic power at all. That doesn't mean he has 3 times her magic power but he has about the same amount of power, just like Gemini.

Comment: Actually, this ability is not that strong. First, he have to make contact with the person who receive his magic power and it seems to at least one minute. Also, if his magic power his limited, it's pretty useless, at least less useful than his others Archives abilities, which are pretty broken.

Comment: his power would have to be at least 3 times as powerful since as I explained before by the time she does it with Gemini she and therefor Gemini also had doubled her power with her second origin and it was still weaker.

Comment: that is true if Hibiki were able to cast the spell himself, but we have no way to confirm he can

Comment: y  couldnt he he knew the spell in the first place

Comment: obviously because of his magic's specificities. as an "archive" user, he is able to manipulate an insane amount of datas. That means he has access to the spell's datas but we have no way to know if he is able to CAST it. As an exemple, I could refer to the magic in general. Some people is Fairy Tail aren't able to use it at all, no matter their magic knowledge.
Otherwise, the way the Urano Metria spell is linked to the stars and because we saw Yukino Agria using it during the Eclipse Spirits arc, it is strongly possible that this spell is only for constellanists.

Comment: but there's nothing to suggest that those who can do magic are only able to do one kind of magic. while they do say that they have an aptitude for certain magic in zero they each chose whaterver they felt like and had no problem using it. sure you have to build up to a point where you can use strong versions of each kind of magic but if that were the case with this spell even if it was a celestial wizard thing lucy shouldn't have been able to cast it since she's super weak at the time.

Comment: as to him transfering power not being broken I'm saying why dont more guilds have people who use archive magic as support people. like they can stay relatively safe for most fights and then a bunch could power one person up later making them completly broken

Comment: I don't know ? ... that's a entirely new question

Comment: thats why its not in the origional question. it's more of a way to exclude an unlikely possible explanation not a genuine question.